# Scala RewriteRules to set namespace & schemaLocation?

Tags: xml, scala, schema

I'm generating an xml file and want to create some transform RewriteRules that will insert the following into the root element:

```
<content
  xmlns:ns="http://example.com/ns"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/ns http://example.com/xml/xsd/xml-schema-articles-v1.0.xsd">
```

It looks [from this gist](https://gist.github.com/tgpfeiffer/3156517) that setting the `xmls:ns` namespace is a matter of creating a NamespaceBinding and applying that as the Elem's scope.  However, I haven't successfully created a RewriteRule for this yet, and I'm still searching for how to add the schema instance (`xmlns:xsi`) and the schemaLocation.

Comment: How are you generating your XML?

Comment: I'm actually reading old xml from a file and using a bunch of  scala.xml.transform RewriteRules to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// start with a sample xml 'document'
val xml = <root attr="willIStayOrWillIGoAway"><container/></root>

// create a namespace binding using TopScope as the "parent" argument 
val ns = new NamespaceBinding("ns", "http://example.com/ns", TopScope)

// create a second namespace binding, and pass "ns" as the new parent argument
val xsi = new NamespaceBinding("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", ns)
```

Notice that we made two [NamespaceBindings](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.8.0/scala/xml/NamespaceBinding.html), but because they are "chained" together, we only need to pass the last one to our RuleTransformer class.

```
// the schemaLocation needs to be a PrefixedAttribute
val schemaLoc = new PrefixedAttribute("xsi", "schemaLocation", "http://example.com/ns http://example.com/xml/xsd/xml-schema-articles-v1.0.xsd", Null)
```

The `xmlns:ns` and `xmlns:xsi` attributes are actually NamespaceBindings - I have no idea why they're handled differently.  But the  `xsi:schemaLocation` is actually a scoped attribute so we use a [PrefixedAttribute](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/scala-xml/#scala.xml.PrefixedAttribute).

```
// in order to limit the insertion to the root node, you'll need it's label
val rootNodeLabel = "root"

// make a new RewriteRule object
val setSchemaAndNamespaceRule = new setNamespaceAndSchema(rootNodeLabel, xsi, schemaLoc)

// apply the rule with a new transformer
val newxml = new RuleTransformer(setSchemaAndNamespaceRule).transform(xml).head
```

Applying the transformer returns this.

```
newxml: scala.xml.Node = 
  <root attr="willIStayOrWillIGoAway"     
        xmlns:ns="http://example.com/ns"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/ns http://example.com/xml/xsd/xml-schema-articles-v1.0.xsd">>
    <container/>
  </root>
```

And this is the class that returns the rewrite rule.

```
// new class that extends RewriteRule
class setNamespaceAndSchema(rootLabel: String, ns: NamespaceBinding, attrs: MetaData) extends RewriteRule {
  // create a RewriteRule that sets this as the only namespace
  override def transform(n: Node): Seq[Node] = n match {

    // ultimately, it's just a matter of setting the scope & attributes
    // on a new copy of the xml node
    case e: Elem if(e.label == rootLabel) =>
      e.copy(scope = ns, attributes = attrs.append(e.attributes))
    case n => n
  }
}
```

Notice that our original attribute is retained; check out how our extended RewriteRule class appends the schemaLocation attribute rather than using it directly.