# Add a XML node to a document namespace-aware in scala

Tags: xml, scala, xml-namespaces

Let's suppose we have the following XML document, parsed in Scala:

```
<ns1:doc-root xmlns:ns1="http://namespace1url.com/schema" xmlns:ns2="http://namespace2url.com/schema">
  <ns1:a>
    <ns2:b>Random content</ns2:b>
  </ns1:a>
</ns1:doc-root>
```

This document comes from a variety of systems and vendors who can decide on the prefix of the namespaces at will. (Even make any of them the default namespace)

So, my task here is to add the following element into the `a` element:

```
<ns1:c>
  <ns2:d>Other random content</ns2:d>
</ns1:c>
```

Here, I know that both elements here, `c` and `d` have the same namespaces as `a` and `b`, respectively. But I don't know what prefix have been chosen for the document. In this example, both the document issuer and I, have chosen `ns1` and `ns2` for the prefixes, but they could (Very probably) be different.

So that the resulting component results as:

```
<ns1:doc-root xmlns:ns1="http://namespace1url.com/schema" xmlns:ns2="http://namespace2url.com/schema">
  <ns1:a>
    <ns2:b>Random content</ns2:b>
    <ns1:c>
      <ns2:d>Other random content</ns2:d>
    </ns1:c>
  </ns1:a>
</ns1:doc-root>
```

Now the question is, **how I manage namespace variations in Scala**? I know how to use `RewriteRule` to iterate through the document adding and removing elements. But **how I know which prefix to use for each element?**

In python, I'd indicate each element namespace and the framework would automagically manage namespace declarations at the root element, prefixes and so...

How can this be done in Scala?

Thank you for your support

Comment: Unless you specify what `ns1` and `ns2` refer to in your sample XML snippet, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: Generally speaking: XML namespaces are *designed* to have freely assignable "shorthands" (i.e. namespace prefixes): "different prefixes" are not "namespace variations". If you write code that relies on a certain namespace always having the same prefix across multiple XML documents, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Tomalak I dont think `ns1` and `ns2` should be further explained. They are just prefixes chosen to represent the document's namespaces. The question topic is about how to know what prefixes are being used for what namespaces and thus, inserting the elements with the correct ones.

I edited the question, nevertheless. So maybe is clearer now.

Comment: That's your misconception. You are looking at this from the wrong end entirely. The prefixes mean **nothing**, the URIs mean **everything**. There is no way to do it with the prefixes alone.

Comment: I know, I know... that's why I am putting the python example. So, how to do it correctly in Scala?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Python or Scala. It works the same in all languages. Create the elements using the namespace URI, not using the prefix. Don't think *"I need to create a `<ns1:c>`"*, think *"I need to create a `<c>` that is in the `http://namespace1url.com/schema` namespace."* Whether `http://namespace1url.com/schema` ends up as `ns1` or something different in the final XML is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Allright, so, how It could be done with the Scala XML library, as part of a RewriteRule in order to insert it in another document? Currently I am just appending a XML literal to the existent Elem, but that is clearly failing because it is not being namespaced

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know enough about Scala to write it down for you, but things should look similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39419520/18771). The `NamespaceBinding` class fulfills the same role that `nsmap` fulfills in [lxml's namespace support](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces). Note the fact that both Python's ElementTree as well as lxml straight-out require that you state the namespace with the element, their syntax for fully qualified names is `{http://namespace1url.com/schema}c` – and *not* `ns1:c`, because that wouldn't make sense.